# Proper method to declare a URL?

Tags: android, file, url, download

In my application, I'm trying to download a file from my website, but I'm having a couple of issues with it. First, I can't seem to figure out the right way to declare the URL. Second, when I run the application it crashes when I tell the connection to get the InputStream. I don't have a clue what I'm doing wrong. I've been searching online for most of the afternoon and have tried many methods to fix the problem with the URL but with no success.

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong so any help given will be greatly appreciated.

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.util.Log;

public class dl_viewKML
{
    String file_path = "";
    String file_url;
    String file_name;

    void downloadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            String file_name = "data.kml";

            //URL url = new URL("http://space.uah.edu");
            String encodedURL = "http:////"+URLEncoder.encode("www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/", "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(encodedURL);
            File file = new File(url + "/" + file_name);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Download beginning: ");
            Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Download url: " + url);
            Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Downloaded file name: " + file_name);

            // Open a connection to the specified URL
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();//crashes here
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            // Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            // Convert the Bytes read to a String.
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Download ready in: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " secs.");
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error: " + e.toString());
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the StackStrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call URLEncoder with url. URLEncoder.encode is used to encode parameters:

so edit your code to:

```
void downloadFile()
{
    try
    {
        String file_name = "data.kml";

        //URL url = new URL("http://space.uah.edu");
        String encodedURL =         "http://"+"www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/data.kml";
        URL url = new URL(encodedURL);

        // Open a connection to the specified URL
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();//crashes here
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        // Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
        {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        // Convert the Bytes read to a String.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Download ready in: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " secs.");
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I did that and now it gives me the error:

Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/data.kml

What causes the http:// to change to /http:/ ? I mean it's a hard coded URL. How is it even changing at all?

Comment: According to my catch statement the url shows the link starting with /http:/ instead of http://

Answer (score 0):

use String encodedURL = "http://www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/";
for Encoding that you applied was not righttake a look at section 3 of RFC3986 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3). It tells you how to encode the various portions of a URI. Unfortunately each portion of the URI (host, path, query, etc.) has slightly different encoding rules.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your manifest, you have declared permission to internet.

You can use the following

```
public class dl_viewKML
{

private static final String encodedURL ="http://www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/";
String file_path = "";
String file_url;
String file_name;

void downloadFile()
{
try
{
    String file_name = "data.kml";

    //URL url = new URL("http://space.uah.edu");

    URL url = new URL(encodedURL);
    File file = new File(url + "/" + file_name);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Download beginning: ");
    Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Download url: " + url);
    Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Downloaded file name: " + file_name);

    // Open a connection to the specified URL
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();//crashes here
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    // Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
    int current = 0;
    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
    {
        baf.append((byte) current);
    }

    // Convert the Bytes read to a String.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
    fos.close();
    Log.d("SHC BalloonSat", "Download ready in: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " secs.");
}

catch (IOException e)
{
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error: " + e.toString());
}

}
```